# Wrong output during API validation response against JSON schema using AJV

Tags: javascript, rest, jsonschema, web-api-testing, ajv

I'm using AJV to validate an API response against JSON schema (swagger). This is the script to do the validation:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = new Ajv();

var schema = {
    "paths": {
      "/users": {
        "get": {
          "security": [
            {
              "3_legged": [
                "userprofile-search"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "parameters": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/parameters/IdentitiesId"
            },
            {
              "$ref": "#/parameters/IdDocumentValue"
            },
            {
              "$ref": "#/parameters/IdDocumentType"
            }
          ],          
          "responses": {
            "200": {
              "headers": {
                "x-correlator": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "format": "uuid",
                }
              },
              "schema": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/UserProfile"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "/users/{user_id}": {
        "get": {
          "security": [
            {
              "3_legged": [
                "userprofile-read"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "tags": [
            "users"
          ],
          "operationId": "getUserProfileInfo",
          "parameters": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/parameters/UserId"
            }
          ],          
          "responses": {
            "200": {
              "description": "OK",
              "headers": {
                "x-correlator": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "format": "uuid",
                  "description": "Correlation id"
                }
              },
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/UserProfile"
              },
              "examples": {
                "application/json": {
                  "id": "A000-0000-0001",
                  "name": "Andrés Iniesta",
                  "id_document": {
                    "country": "ES",
                    "type": "NIF",
                    "value": "value"
                  },
                  "identities": [
                    {
                      "type": "email",
                      "id": "id",
                      "services": [
                        "iptv",
                        "email"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "phone_number",
                      "id": "id",
                      "services": [
                        "mobile"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "phone_number",
                      "id": "id",
                      "services": [
                        "mobile"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "phone_number",
                      "id": "id",
                      "services": [
                        "landline",
                        "broadband"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
  "definitions": {
    "UserProfile": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "id",
        "name",
        "identities"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "id_document": {
          "$ref": "common.json#/definitions/IdDocument"
        },
        "identities": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Identity"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Identity": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "id",
        "services",
        "type"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "phone_number",
            "email",
            "uid"
          ]
        },
        "services": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "mobile",
              "invoicing"
            ]
          }
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var common = {
  "definitions": {
    "MoneyAmount": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "amount": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      }
    },
    "IdDocument": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "country",
        "type",
        "value"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "country": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var response={
    "id": "123456789",
    "name": "pruebas trocafone prepago",
    "id_document": {
        "country": "ARG",
        "type": "P",
        "value": "15042016"
    },
    "identities": [
        {
            "type": "uid",
            "services": [
                "invoicing"
            ],
            "id": "511644813"
        },
        {
            "type": "phone_number",
            "services": [
                "mobile"
            ],
            "id": "00123456789"
        },
        {
            "type": "email",
            "services": [
                "email"
            ],
            "id": ""
        }
    ]
}

ajv.addSchema(schema, 'user_profile.json');
ajv.addSchema(common, 'common.json');

var testajv = ajv.compile({ $ref: 'common.json#/definitions/IdDocument' });

console.log(testajv(JSON.stringify(response)), testajv.errors);
```

Then, I get this output:

```
schema id ignored A000-0000-0001
false [ { keyword: 'type',
    dataPath: '',
    schemaPath: 'common.json#/definitions/IdDocument/type',
    params: { type: 'object' },
    message: 'should be object' } ]
```

1- I don't understand why ajv tell me that the "schema id" is ignored. Why does it important?

2- Why does it tell me that IdDocument/type "should be object"? It is object in the response, defined as follow:

```
"id_document": {
    "country": "ARG",
    "type": "P",
    "value": "15042016"
}
```

Could someone help me to understand it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swagger Schema is NOT a JSON Schema, therefore you have to address a correct place in Swagger Schema (`schema.definitions.UserProfile`).

Though Swagger Definition is not 100% compatible with JSON Schema, in most of cases you can use generic validator.

More info: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#schemaObject.

You need to remove `JSON.stringify`, as it creates a `string` from your data (`string` is not an `object`).

```
ajv.addSchema(schema.definitions.UserProfile, 'user_profile.json');
ajv.addSchema(common, 'common.json');

var testajv = ajv.compile({ $ref: 'common.json#/definitions/IdDocument' });

console.log(testajv(response), ajv.errorsText(testajv.errors));
```

https://runkit.com/embed/kn4gp1fs8vat

Comment: Ok, understood. Why do we get "data should have required property 'country'" in the runkit output? I've got the same running it in my mac. The country keyword is defined as required and is within the response as well. Any idea?

Comment: The problem with missing country caused by discrepancy between your data (which is UserProfile) and the schema that you use (which is IdDocument). If you use UserProfile schema the error should be gone.